# Can't print an attribute of my own class in python

Tags: python, object, int, typeerror, callable

I get the error:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

when I try to do something like this:

```
first = Rational()
print(first.numerator())
```

below is my code:

```
class Rational:

def __init__(self, numerator=0, denominator=1):
    self.numerator = numerator
    self.denominator = denominator

def numerator(self):
    return self.numerator

def denominator(self):
    return self.denominator

def __str__(self):     
    return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)
```

It appears that python thinks that numerator is of type int, but I thought I made it as an attribute of the Rational Class. I'm terribly confused.

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: You aren't indenting it the way you pasted the code here right? I am right now not at a machine where I can run Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `numerator`s in your code...  ;-)
You have one attribute called `numerator` on the first line of the `__init__` method and another one as a method defined by `def numerator(self)`.
There are different possibilities depending on what you need:

1. Delete the method and use always `first.numerator`.
2. Rename the attribute so that they have no conflicts.
3. Use a `@property` clause, but I don't think why you would do that in this case, because there is nothing to calculate or modify to the attribute,

Comment: Perfect! If you consider it solved, do not forget to mark my answer as the selected one. ;-)    Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

```
class Rational:

    def __init__(self, numerator=0, denominator=1):
        self._numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    @property
    def numerator(self):
        return self._numerator
```

Then your calling code would look like:

```
first = Rational()
print(first.numerator)
```

What's happening in your code is that `Rational.numerator` is being bound to the method you're defining at module import time, as per normal. However, your `__init__` method is explicitly saying "create an instance attribute named `denominator` bound to this int object". That new instance attribute is resolved before the class attribute with the same name, so any references to `instance.denominator` will resolve to that instance attribute.

My suggested replacement, if you truly want to implement a getter (which isn't particularly Pythonic; you already have a way to access `instance.denominator` built-in!), is to store it in a privately-named variable and create a publicly-named property method that loads its value and returns it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick. Still getting the same error. Essentially the "_" before the attribute makes it private to only within the class?

Comment: Well, you have to decide which calling semantics you want for `.numerator`. Should it act like an int and return an int value, or should it act like a function and be called like one? If you truly want the function semantics, remove the `@property` decorator and access it like `instance.numerator()`. I'd personally recommend just access the `.numerator` and `.denominator` attributes directly without going through getter methods, though.